# How to implement different kinds of return to the same query using Room and Android Rx?

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-kotlin2

I'm facing this problem. Im using room to create the local database of my app. Let's say i have an Entity call User and a UserDao. It looks like this:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao: BaseDao<User>{
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE remote_id = :remoteId")
    fun getUser(remoteId : Long) : Single<User>
}
```

Nothing weird in this point, but what i want to do is be able to Changue the type of return in these  functions. I want this because sometimes i need to get a Single but in other cases i need to get a Flowable. In this two cases the query is the same an the only thing than chagues is the type of return and i don't want to do something like this.

```
@Dao
interface UserDao: BaseDao<User>{

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE remote_id = :remoteId")
    fun getUserSingle(remoteId : Long) : Single<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE remote_id = :remoteId")
    fun getUserFlowable(remoteId : Long) : Flowable<User>
 }
```

Any idea how to do this in a clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use your `Single<User>` and call `toFlowable()` on it.
Something like `getUserSingle().toFlowable()` on your dao object.

**EDIT**

You can us flowable operator and call it something like `getUserFlowable.firstOrError()` . because from the documentation

> Returns a Single that emits only the very first item emitted by this Flowable or signals a {@link NoSuchElementException} if this Flowable is empty

Comment: But if i do that, any kind of update is never gonna be update it. Or am i wrong? with that method, it is gonna retrieve any kind of update in the user table?

Comment: how about using the flowable operator and call it something like `getUserFlowable.firstOrError()`? because from the documentations 
> Returns a Single that emits only the very first item emitted by this Flowable or signals a {@link NoSuchElementException} if this Flowable is empty.

Comment: Yeah it sounds better, i din't find these method at reading, tnx for the coment :D. im gonna see how it works

Comment: Let me know if this works. I'll edit my answer then.

Comment: I keep looking for a better way, using generics types, but room is very restricted to generic code, so your answe is the best. So, create an answer plz :D